# What are these icons next to the line numbers in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In some of my C++ files in Visual Studio 2010, there are these strange icons next to the line numbers.  I cannot click on them, right click on them, or interact with them in any way.  The only thing I can do is move / delete lines of code and these icons follow the line they are on / get deleted when the line is deleted.

I have looked everywhere but have found nothing.  Can someone tell me what these are?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are bookmarks.

You can remove a bookmark using the menu option `Edit -> Bookmarks -> Toggle bookmark` or pressing `Ctrl+K` twice.

You can use `Edit -> Bookmarks -> Clear bookmarks` or press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L` to remove all bookmarks in the file.

The purpose of the bookmarks is that you can quickly jump between them.